# Что это var dragObject = {};?

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять чем в этом коде является **var dragObject = {};** и что это вообще? Конструктор функции присвоен этому элементу внутри этой же функции?

```
  var DragManager = new function() {
    
        var dragObject = {};
    
        var self = this;
    
        function onMouseDown(e) {
    
            if (e.which != 1) return;
    
            var elem = e.target.closest('.draggable');
            if (!elem) return;
    
            dragObject.elem = elem;
    
            dragObject.downX = e.pageX;
            dragObject.downY = e.pageY;
    
            return false;
        }
    }
```

А более не понятно как там оказался elem **(dragObject.elem)** если он не был упомянут прежде в той области. С JS редко работаю так что прошу прощения если вопрос глуп.
[Вот ссылка на полный проект](https://plnkr.co/edit/e5KajSW68fwNteuQ?p=preview&preview)

Comment: `var dragObject = {}` это новый пустой объект, поле elem создается в нем в момент первого присваивания

Comment: @Stranger in the Q создали пустой объект который может хранить элементы. Далее мы можем добавить туда элемент подобным действием dragObject.elem? Не привычно из-за этого уточняю.

Comment: так точно, только нужно присваивание, тоесть знак раенства, как у Вас в примере `dragObject.elem = ...`;

Comment: @Stranger in the Q огромное спасибо за помощь.

Comment: да нет проблем :)

Comment: @Al-Tamir по хорошему конечно лучше сразу обозначить объект и задать ему значения по умолчанию, чем дальше разбираться что там в нем будет положено.

Comment: @MoloF спасибо что предупредили, а то я подумал что это для JS программистов практичнее, а самому так делать не привычно. Лучше уж буду заранее все элементы вносить.